# A version of strcopy function that copies integer arrays

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, integer

I have tried to replicate aa strcopy() function that deals with integer arrays in ANSI-C as an exercise to get familiar with functions.
Here is a code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int array[10] = {0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int * pointer1;
    int * pointer2 = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    int i;

    //assign first pointer
    pointer1 = array;

    //print pointer1
    printf("Pointer1's array : \n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",*(pointer1+i));
    }   
    printf("\n");

    //copy pointer1 to pointer2
    intCopy(pointer1,pointer2);

    //print pointer2's array 
    printf("Pointer2's array: \n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",*(pointer2+i));
    }
    printf("\n");



    free(pointer2);
    return 0;
}
//copy an integer array
int intCopy(int  * input, int * output)
{

    //copy input to ouput element by element
    while((*output++=*input++) != '\0')
    {
        //copy each element until null terminator is found;
        output++;
        input++;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

The code was suppose to make pointer2 behave like pointer1 but with a new copy of the array.
However, when I tried printing the integers which pointer2 should be able to point to I got this:-
Pointer2's array:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I copied the code for the strcopy straight from the textbook and have no idea how only the first
element is copied successfully. I appreciate the help.

EDIT: I have removed the extra incrementation done in the intCopy() function and the output is still   the same.

Comment: I am trying to deal with integer arrays here.

Comment: Why is it a string copy when you are copying integers? Any why would an array of integers be terminated by a 0 valued integer?

Comment: And aside from the bug pointed out by pablo1977, your source array starts with a 0 element - so the copy wouldn't get very far anyway.

Comment: I have edited the code and the output is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 problems:

1) Incrementing pointer twice, only once is needed as also pointed out by @pablo1977

```
while((*output++=*input++) != '\0') {
  // output++;  // delete these 2 lines
  // input++;
}
```

2) Array to copy has first element of 0.  This acts as a terminating condition in `intCopy()`

```
int array[10] = {0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
// --------------^
```

---

Strings in C are arrays of `char` up to an including a terminating `'\0'`.  To mimic a "string of int" using an array of `int`, the `int` array also needs to terminate with a `0`.  The OP supplied array's *first* element is a `0`, thus only the first element, a `0`, is copied.  As OP also printed out 9 additional "0", the later 9 values just happened to be `0` as this is UB.

OP needs to either pass to `intCopy()` the number of elements (then the array need not terminate with a `0` and may contain `0` elements.) or insure the source array has a terminating `0` (in which case the first `0` is also the last element).  OP did the 2nd, but the terminating `0` is also the first element.

As with any such copying, coding also much insure the destinaiton is of adequate size.

Comment: Did not notice @Michael Burr insightful comment until after I posted. ( which is point #2 here).

Answer (score 2):

An array of characters interpreted as a string has, by convention, a terminating `\0` character as the last character in the array. Because of this, a string copy function can be written without knowing the string length beforehand. An array of ints has no such special values, so the size of the array needs to be passed in and used in the loop test condition.

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing the pointers twice. This will bring wrong results.

The variables `success` and `i` are not playing any role at all.

To mimic a little more the `strcpy()` standard function you could add the qualifier `restrict` to each parameter of `stringCopy()`, which at least suggest to the coder that the parameters shall not intersect.

**CHANGED:** The OP has changed the parameters to have type `int`.
However, the condition to end the loop (comparisson against 0) seems now arbitrary, since integer arrays are not null-terminated.

Besides, the double increment of pointers in the loop is still wrong.

Comment: what do you mean by restrict qualifiers? none of that is mention in my textbook.

Comment: I am still working on other features of the program by success so ignore it for now. I am using i so that I don't have to reset the pointer position every time I iterate through the array.

Comment: I have fixed the double incrementation and still the output is the same.

Comment: chux showed you the problem. I've already said in my answer that 0-termination condition in the loop has no sense.